# How to resign textfield as first responder in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I use this code to resign my `UITextField` as `firstResponder` when using a standard `UIView`.

But I now have `UITextField` in my `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView`, and the code does not resign the textfield as first responder when I click outside of the textField.  Any ideas how to make this work?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([self.temperatureTextField isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != self.temperatureTextField) {
        [self.temperatureTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`[[self tableView] endEditing:YES];` is my standard approach.

Comment: @Faisal, Wherever I want to resign the first responder. It varies with different situations. In your case, assuming your touchesBegan:withEvent is being called, putting it there should work.

Comment: I tried that and can't get it to dismiss when I click outside the `UITextField` still.  The code I posted works fine when the `UITextField` is independent and not inside of a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @Faisal, in that case, there was probably something wrong with the delivery of touch events. I'm guessing the method was just never called?

Comment: I actually added your code to my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Matt Wilding's answer for the specific case of UITableView, the approach I use is as follows:
What we usually want is basically to hide the keyboard on two scenarios: on tapping outside of the Text UI elements, or on scrolling down/up the UITableView. The first scenario we can easily add via a TapGestureRecognizer, and the second via the UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewWillBeginDragging: method.
First order of business, the method to hide the keyboard:

```
   /**
     *  Shortcut for resigning all responders and pull-back the keyboard
     */
    -(void)hideKeyboard
    {
        //this convenience method on UITableView sends a nested message to all subviews, and they resign responders if they have hold of the keyboard
        [self.tableView endEditing:YES];

    }
```

This method resigns any textField UI of the subviews within the UITableView view hierarchy, so it's more practical than resigning every single element independently.

Next we take care of dismissing via outside Tap gesture, with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self setupKeyboardDismissGestures];

}

- (void)setupKeyboardDismissGestures
{

//    Example for a swipe gesture recognizer. it was not set-up since we use scrollViewDelegate for dissmin-on-swiping, but it could be useful to keep in mind for views that do not inherit from UIScrollView
//    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
//    swipeUpGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
//    swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
//    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGestureRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    //this prevents the gestureRecognizer to override other Taps, such as Cell Selection
    tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

}
```

Setting  tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView to NO is to avoid the gestureRecognizer from overriding the normal inner workings of the UITableView (for example, not to interfere with cell Selection).

Finally, to handle hiding the keyboard on Scrolling up/down the UITableView, we must implement the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol scrollViewWillBeginDragging: method, as:

.h file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

.m file

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self hideKeyboard];
}
```

I hope it helps! =)