# resignFirstResponder with Text Field is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have four UITextFields and associated each with an outlet in .h files. I have also defined 4 dismiss function for each textfield as shown below:

```
- (IBAction)dismiss1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dismiss2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dismiss3:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dismiss4:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *weight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *age;
```

Implementation of dismiss function in the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)dismiss1:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)dismiss2:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}

...
```

I am very sure that the outlet is connected to each UITextFiled correctly. The IBAction of each dismiss function is also connected with 'Editing did end' event correspondingly. However, when I ran the app using simulator, the keyboard will not dismiss when I click 'Enter/Done'. It's also very weird that when I place the breakpoint inside the dismiss function, clicking 'Enter' when typing in the corresponding UITextField does not bring up the debugger.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Update: I checked the object type of sender (dismiss1) using breakpoint and it's UITextFiled. However, I did not entered the debugging mode when I click 'Enter' in the first TextField, but entered the debugging mode when I click on the second TextField (before typing).

Comment: Cast your sender object to UITextField Object and try again.

Comment: Did you set UITextfields delegate you controller in Storyboard? "Editing did end" need not required IBAction method you could Just declare method and connect in Storyboard for "Editing did end" and write resignFirstResponder in impementation

Comment: Try using break points in your dismiss methods and check the type of the sender. Also use [self.view endEditing:YES]; in your dismiss methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `UITextFielDelegate`

```
textfieldname.delegate = self;
```

use this code it will resolve your issue

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;

}
```

Comment: I don't see how this code could possibly work, all the if statements seem to be doing the same.

Comment: Why do you need the if-else statements? :/ You are doing the same thing regardless to whatever instance of textfield it is. Just resign and return yes

Answer (score 1):

Use the code to resign keyBoard without specify textFiled name.

```
- (IBAction)dismiss1:(UITextField*)sender {
  [self.view endEditing:true];
  // or use [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: check your object type

Comment: @WenjunWu - your text field under with in UIVIew or UIscrollview

Comment: @ Wenjun Wu .dismiss1 is connected with IBOutlet.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik My text field is in a UI Table View. Does this matters?

Comment: @WenjunWu - yes , is the prboem , change the resign as `[[self yourtableViewName] endEditing:YES]` for more information see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248477/how-to-resign-textfield-as-first-responder-in-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

Add text field delegate

```
name.delegate = self;
email.delegate = self;

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create four actions for textfield

You can set delegate of Textfield and use following method

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Inside this method you can compare your textfield with method returning textfield and get you task done in "if" condition

Hope it help you!!

Answer (score 0):

The `Editing did end` is called when a textfield did lose the "focus", mean it is not the first responder any more (because it has resigned or an other one became first responder).

Use [`textFieldShouldReturn`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn) to detect when the return key is called.

And call `resignFirstResponder` on the texfield when this is called. The `Editing did end` event will occur after that.

Edit : you have to implement something (Your ViewController?) as delegate of the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

**Assign the tag to different textfields**
then >

```
textfield.delegate = self;

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
if(textfield.tag==num)
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
   return YES;
}
```